# Simplest Routing For URL Queries

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, url-routing

I'm stuck trying to figure out the best approach to my problem. I want to pass query params with a / than a ?.

So for example, instead of:

`https://example.com/search.php?q=test`

It'd be:

`https://example.com/search/test/`

I'm not using any PHP framework. How can I reach my goal?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.server.php `array_pop (explode ("/",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))`  will give you test when the url is `https://example.com/search/test/`. In your index explode the whole url and call the right php file in function (with a switch)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with your .htaccess file.

For that you need to write in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1
```

The first line activate your RewriteEngine, so you can write RewriteRules as much you like.

In the second line you define your first RewriteRule:

In the URL it need to be `search/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/`.
That means, you only allow the characters inside the square bracket.
Then you redirect to your wanted script, in this case its `search.php` with the GET Parameter.

It's also possible to do this with more parameters or much more. For that you should google maybe "htaccess Explanation".

Answer (score -1):

Better try php router and dont waste the time for rewrite !!!
And test nginx server it is awesome.